# Web Browser Security Rules, How do I view my file without file:// in the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm trying to use Bootstraps v3.3.7 and its Carousel template. I know that how I am coding (simple html files in Sublime text that I then open in Chrome) will not allow me to see the Carousel features because of Web Browser Security Rules. How do I view my webpages without the "file://" in front of its local html file name? I want to make sure this code works, but I don't know where to host it in order to see it in action.

[This is the carousel I am trying to use.](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)

EDIT:
Here is the code. I'm unsure if this will help because you can access it on the site above too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>


  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->


<!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
================================================== -->
<!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

<div class="container marketing">

  <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->


  <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

  <hr class="featurette-divider">

  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="featurette-divider">

  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="featurette-divider">

  <div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="featurette-divider">

  <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer>
    <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Comment: will be necesary mount a web-server like apche, or node, or...

Comment: I was going to get XAMPP but I didn't think it was necessary for a simple html site. Do you think it is?

Comment: If *all* the resources are local it may work. It will be easiest just to setup a local HTTP server (this doesn't sound like a full "XAMPP" stack is required, just something to host static HTTP files).

Comment: yes it will be necesary, because by default browser block js in local

Comment: Use tiny web server : 1: Install node 2: npm i -g http-server 3: terminal, go to dir and type http-server -c-1, it will print how you can visit your project's page via browser.

Comment: You need a simple webserver. Maybe a [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)/LAMP/[MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) solution will be easier if you're a beginner, but i suggest you to search for [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) or [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: _"I was going to get XAMPP but I didn't think it was necessary for a simple html site. Do you think it is?"_ You can launch chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set.